# What is the difference between 'Burning Fat' and 'Burning Calories'?

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat

What is the difference between 'Burning Fat' and 'Burning Calories'?

I feel I am over-weighted. To reduce my weight, how to know whether I need to burn calories or fat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calories are energy factors, and you burn them in several ways:

- **At rest**, your body burns calories as energy (that it gets either from food and nutrients Or from your body fat) to keep glands,hormones, and organs working normally.
- **when you exercises**, you stress your body and thus require more oxygen and energy for your muscles, bodily hormones and organs to stay alive and recuperate. Your body regulates these by burning calories as energy source (as said above, that it gets either from food and nutrients Or from your body fat)

So you start **burning fat** when actually the calories that you **consume** are **less** than the energy you expand during the day.
It means, that for example if your body at **Rest** requires let's say 2000 calories per day , and u do the following (an example):

- you eat 1800 calories on this day
- you exercise and burn say 100 calories as energy

  **-->** Thus, you have a deficit of calories : 

  **2000-1800= 200 added to 100 calories from exercise ==> 300 calories deficit per day.**

This is how you start **using fat** from ur body to compensate, and to loose **1 pound of fat per week** u need a **deficit of 3500 calories per week** ( which is 500 calories deficit per day. it is not recommended to have more than **700 cal** deficit **per day** for health purpose).